# Why is there a difference in advanced serial port options on Windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port

I was looking into advanced serial options on Windows, but my options didn't seem to match up with the advanced options I've seen online. Is there a reason for a difference in advanced options?

**On my Windows machine, my serial options are:**

[image]

**Here's example of the advanced settings I've seen online:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They will be the policy of the device driver (or hardware) vendor.

The place you marked is the configuration information that exists in the Windows API.
 (However, latency has its own possibility)

Rather, some of the Miscellaneous Options are proprietary.

Many configuration information is defined by the API, but there is no definition as to whether to retain/discard their values inside the device driver before opening or after closing.
This vendor seems to have decided to hold them.

By preparing these setting methods as their own control panel, it seems to be appealing vendor's technological capabilities and competitive advantage.

Comment: So it's based on the device driver installed, so some devices will give you different advanced options?

Comment: @karamazovbros, For example, for I/O devices that can not handle high-speed/high-throughput communication, it is conceivable that delay can be set between each byte of transmission, and so on.

Comment: Does the driver have a classification that it isn't high-speed/high-throughput communication, so Windows knows it doesn't have advanced options?

Comment: There is no such classification in the driver, it depends on the connected equipment. For example, imagine connecting a mechanical teletypewriter like exhibiting at a museum. Even at a low speed of 300 bps, it takes time to print one character, and data will be lost unless you add a delay between letters. Regarding the inter-character delay, it does not exist in the communication standard, so it does not exist as the specification of the device driver API.

Comment: How does Windows tell from the connected equipment?

Comment: There is no mechanism/specification as OS. It depends on the arrangement between the application and the equipment. Furthermore, interfaces such as serial port/parallel port etc are not recommended as being legacy and support is decreasing.